# Excel sheet downloaded from google drive via asp.net core code is not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to download an Excel sheet from Google Drive using ASP.NET Core. The code is working, but the downloaded file doesn't have the same formatting than it has on Drive.

Here is the code:

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadFile(string fileId)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var url = $"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{fileId}";

    var scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, };
    //Using Desktop client Approach
    var clientId = "my client id";
    var clientSecret = "my client secret";
    var secrets = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret };

    try
    {
        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes, "CIS Test Server", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).ConfigureAwait(true);

        using var _service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Demo App"
        });

        var file = _service.Files.Get(fileId);
        file.MediaDownloader.Download(url, ms);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Here is the required formatting:

[image: Required Format]

Here is what we're getting:

[image: Format we are getting]

Also, there is a message shown when we open the downloaded file:

> Javascript is not enabled on your browser so this file can't be opened  enable and reload.

Comment: have you tried after enabling javascript in your browser ?

Comment: karthik thanks for reply.....actually i am trying downloading it from backend code, not using browser.

Comment: What library are you using? `DriveService` doesn't seem to be part of the official .NET client.

Comment: Hello maart I am using  Google.Apis.Download, Google.Apis.Drive and Google.Apis.Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually downloading the actual page, not the spreadsheet itself.

You cannot download an spreadsheet directly, as it's a Google Docs file. You need to export it into another format (for example CSV). To do that you need to use `var request = _service.Files.Export(fileId, "text/csv")` and then download it with [one of the methods available](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ExportRequest.html#methods) (for example `DownloadAsync`). Obviously you can change the MIME type to your needs.

### References

- [`FileResource` method: `Export(String, String)` (.NET API reference)](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.html#Google_Apis_Drive_v3_FilesResource_Export_System_String_System_String_)
- [`ExportRequest` methods (.NET API reference)](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ExportRequest.html#methods)